# How to edit the value of a Text Field using Graphical Layout view (Eclipse Android Development Tool)

Tags: android, adk, graphical-layout-editor

I don't understand what is going on when I am in the Graphical layout window in the Eclipse Android Development tool (v22.6.2-1085508) and want to change the text of a TextView. I saw other questions/answers on how to do it programmatically. But unless I am overlooking something obvious the process to do it using the GUI seems very laborious and non-intutive.

Here is the steps I went through:

1. Start with the default Android Application project. I Want to change text: "Hello World"
2. I find that I can't modify the textView inline (i.e. visual studio style).
3. So I select Edit (F2)
4. But now I find I can't really "edit" the resource https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBtXL.jpg
5. So I click on the "New String" button.
6. And create a whole new resource with the new text string that I want.

The screen shots: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yAcLz.jpg

Can someone clue me in to the philosophy behind this Graphical interface? Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: just go to the .xml file and you can edit all you want.

Comment: In the xml view: `android:text="Whatever you want"` or (better), reference a string reaource: `android:text="@string/your_string_name"`

Comment: yep that works. But what's the point of the graphical view if I can't use it to make simple modifications like changing the text.

Comment: ... disposing components and have a graphical preview?

Comment: Go to the xml code manually and add text and hit CTRL+SPACE . it will do it automatically just add your text inside

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you aren't using the editor correctly:

[image]

Here you see I defined `@string/help` for the **Text** property
And you correctly read "User guide", as defined in `strings.xml`

Alternatively, in the xml view, you can add your TextView the attribute:

```
android:text="Whatever you want"
```

or (better), reference a string resource (as in my example):

```
android:text="@string/your_string_name"
```